# Diverging barplot with extreme values hides bars with small values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a diverging barplot with ggplot. On one side of the y-axis, I want to plot bars with large values, while on the other side, I want to plot bars with small values. I already have some code which creates the type of plot that I want, however the high values on the right side of the y-axis seem to squish the y-axis on the left side of the plot, causing the bars with small values to be hidden. See my code below for an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data
df <- data.frame (Name  = c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D1","D2","D3","D4"),
                  Variable = c("group_1","group_1","group_1","group_1","group_2","group_2","group_2","group_2"),
                  Value = c(10, 20, 5, 12, 21558091, 20952575, 17442644, 20340241))

# To create divergent bars, the values of one group will be assigned as negatives
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Variable == "group_2",
                        Value,
                        -1*Value))

# Create the plot (plot1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Name, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-30, -15, 0, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000, 25000000),
                     labels =  c(30, 15, 0, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000, 25000000)) +
  ylim(-30, 25000000)

# Bars from group_1 cannot be seen due to the squished y-axis on the left side 

# Forcing the ylim to a small region shows that the group_1 bars are in fact present (plot2) 
ggplot(df, aes(x = Name, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  ylim(-30, 10)
```

The first plot from the code above does not show bars from group_1 due to the squished y-axis on the left side:
[image]

By forcing the ylim to be restricted to the small portion of the left side of the plot, you can see the group_1 bars (second plot from code above):
[image]

My desired output should work with extremely large values on the right side and small values at the left side of the plot. If there is no real solution for this problem, what could be some alternative to compare such small and extremely high values?

Comment: Could try meeting separate plots and connecting with patchwork, cowplot, ggarrange or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the group 1 values by a large number, and then scale the y-axis labels by the same factor.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data
df <- data.frame (Name  = c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D1","D2","D3","D4"),
                  Variable = c("group_1","group_1","group_1","group_1","group_2","group_2","group_2","group_2"),
                  Value = c(10, 20, 5, 12, 21558091, 20952575, 17442644, 20340241))

# To create divergent bars, the values of one group will be assigned as negatives
mult <- 10^6 #multiplication factor
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Variable == "group_2",
                        Value,
                        -1 * Value * mult)) 

breaks <-  c( 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000, 25000000)
# Create the plot (plot1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Name, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-breaks, 0, breaks),
                     labels =  c(breaks / mult, 0, breaks))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use facets with free scales to separate the bars based on the sign of `Value`, then mask the fact that you're using facets. Example below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data
df <- data.frame (Name  = c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D1","D2","D3","D4"),
                  Variable = c("group_1","group_1","group_1","group_1","group_2","group_2","group_2","group_2"),
                  Value = c(10, 20, 5, 12, 21558091, 20952575, 17442644, 20340241))

# To create divergent bars, the values of one group will be assigned as negatives
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Variable == "group_2",
                        Value,
                        -1*Value))

ggplot(df, aes(Value, Name, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_blank(aes(x = Value * 1.1)) + # Fake scale expansion
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_grid(~ sign(Value), scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"),
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great option, however, any idea on how to remove the double 0.00 at the middle of the value axis?

Comment: You could use [facetted position scales](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/reference/facetted_pos_scales.html), but Richard's answer is way easier. Disclaimer: I wrote that function in the link.